# monitor performance with JPA + Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, caching, tomcat, jpa

What are the tools and approaches you suggest to use for monitoring performance? My app is running on Tomcat, Spring 3, JPA, Hibernate and solr. I've noticed some lag/slow activity on a certain page.
The app does not have any code of cache setup. Or even connection pooling.

Pardon my beginner-style questions, I'm only entering the "performance monitoring" world just now...

I know couple of things to look at is- dabatase calls, connection pooling, indexed tables, caching etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You absolutely need connection pooling. It's a no-brainer, there are libraries like [Bone CP](http://jolbox.com/), [Commons DBCP](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/) or [c3p0](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/) that do this transparently.
2. You must implemented automated load/stress test. [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) is pretty easy to use, other tools like that are [Gatling](http://gatling-tool.org/) and [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/).
3. Enable SQL logging and statistics. Most likely too many or too complex queries are slowing down your page.
4. Use a **profiler**. Either commercial ([JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), [YourKit](http://www.yourkit.com/)) or the one included in [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html).

Comment: thanks Tomasz. we're using JPATransactionManager and there's no configuration of any connection pooling in the datasource configuration (at least that I can see in the code - is there any other way to verify if it's already implemented?). If I wanted to use c3p0 conn pooling, I'd have to add it to the datasource xml config, right?

Comment: @Reet: `JPATransactionManager` is irrelevant, transaction manager points to some `DateSource`, check out what kind of data source is it.

Comment: we're using org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource, I understand now that I should add config for parameters such as initialSize etc. How would I be able to test the new performance numbers after conn. pooling?

Comment: @Reet: so you *are* using connection pooling. You can experiment with different configuration values. Disregard point 1. and proceed with the remaining ones.

Comment: @Thomasz, so by virtue of using dbcp.BasicDataSource, it means that I'm using conn.pooling? What about where can I change the config values? The code I have is ... <bean id="oneDataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"
          p:driverClassName="${one.datasource.class}"
          p:url="${one.datasource.url}"
          p:username="${one.datasource.username}"
          p:password="${one.datasource.password}"/>

</beans>

Comment: @Reet: yes, DBCP **is** connection pool implementation (and not much more than that). Check out [JavaDoc of `BasicDataSource`](http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/apidocs/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html) for more options, e.g. `p:maxActive`. But are you sure pooling is the bottleneck?

Comment: @Thomasz, No, I'm not sure yet that that is the only issue.. I'm curious, what happens if you dont configure maxActive, or minimum number of connections?
Does that mean it'll open any number of connections, and cause issue? I'll go through DBCP literature online too to figure how exactly it works!

Comment: Thanks Thomasz, I learnt a lot with your help. And found the default values to all those parameters here: http://commons.apache.org/dbcp/configuration.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use this application to monitor your application:

http://newrelic.com/

He has a free plan!